# How can I generate an email with a subject line with international characters in it?

Tags: email, header

The content encoding headers define how the body of the message is to be interpreted, but the subject is a header, and isn't subject (ha ha) to the declaration of the content type/encoding headers.

Is there a way to make international character set subject lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047  defines encoding of non-ascii characters in headers.

```
"=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [RFC 2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047) specifies how.